# Dynamic SQL for checking stored procedure existence

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I want to execute this query using dynamic SQL, but it doesn't affect the `@Exists` variable. What is the problem?

Purpose: check whether a stored procedure with name `@TransformProcName` exists in the database `@TargetDb`:

```
SET @Sql = N'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TargetServer) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@TargetDB) + ' 
                WHERE type = ''P'' AND OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N'''+QUOTENAME(@TargetSchema)+'.'+QUOTENAME(@TransformProcName)+'''))
                    SET @Exists = 0
             ELSE
                    SET Exists = 1'

EXEC sp_executesql @Sql,N'@Exists bit OUTPUT', @Exists OUTPUT
```

Comment: Is this supposed to check existence on a remote server (`@TargetServer`)? If so, you'll need a bit more than `sp_executesql`. (The rest of the query doesn't make much syntactic sense either -- always `PRINT` to see the results of dynamic SQL before you actually run it.)

Comment: `SET Exists = 1` should be `SET @Exists = 1`

Comment: Param names are misleading a bit. You use one dot notation that is schemaname.tablename while naming params `@TargetServer`, `@TargetDB`.

Comment: Jeroen, yes, I want to check it on the remote server. Can you please explain what I need to do this instead of sp_executesql?

Comment: I rollback'd your edit because deleting 502 characters from the body of your question meant it didn't make sense any more. Remember that SO is not just a resource for you to get the answer you want but to serve as a reference library for future visitors having the same problem to get help

Comment: if you want to remove sensitive info (what is sensitive here I wonder?) change just the sensitive strings I'll redact. But _you cannot delete the whole code_. If you want _post dissociation_ instead, just say so.

Comment: Jean-François Fabre, what is the purpose of editing sensitive information if it will be shown in edit history anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of problems here. Firstly you had `SET Exists = 1`, which should be `SET @Exists = 1`, but you also were referring to an invalid object. You'll need to use `sys.procedures` and `sys.schemas` here, and you can't use `OBJECT_ID` as that'll be run in the context of the database you're connected to. This gives you the following (also tidied up the dynamic SQL):

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

DECLARE @TargetServer sysname, @TargetDB sysname, @TargetSchema sysname, @TransformProcName sysname;

SET @TargetDB = N'Sandbox';
SET @TargetSchema = N'dbo';
SET @TransformProcName = N'sample_sp';

DECLARE @Exists bit;


SET @Sql = N'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT *' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'               FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TargetServer) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@TargetDB) + '.sys.procedures p' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'                    JOIN sys.schemas s ON p.schema_id = s.schema_id' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'               WHERE p.[name] = @TransformProcName' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'                 AND s.[name] = @TargetSchema)' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'       SET @Exists = 0' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'ELSE' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'       SET @Exists = 1;'


PRINT @SQl;
EXEC sp_executesql @Sql,N'@TransformProcName sysname, @TargetSchema sysname, @Exists bit OUTPUT', @TransformProcName = @TransformProcName, @TargetSchema = @TargetSchema, @Exists =  @Exists OUTPUT;
PRINT @Exists;
```

Comment: This isn't actually using `@TargetServer`, which from the comments is apparently necessary.

Comment: Yeah, I'd taken that out on my end because I didn't have a linked server to test against

Comment: `sp_addlinkedserver 'local'`, `sp_setnetname 'local', '.'`. MS does not officially support linked servers going back to the local machine, but 1) as far as I can tell it still always works fine and 2) for testing purposes it's obviously OK.

Comment: I've put the parameter back in, but will admit I didn't test, so may be a typo. It did work prior however

Comment: You forgot + before the QUOTENAME(@TargetServer) and mention this variable in EXEC line, but after correction, it works great!

Comment: `@TargetServer` doesn't need to be in the `EXEC` line @RomanNekliukov. The value is quoted, and injected, in the `SET` statement.